# Was bedeutet "in die Gewichtung fallen" und wie kann ich das anders sagen?

Tags: meaning

Was bedeutet "in die Gewichtung fallen"?

> [..] große Werte könnten stärker in die Gewichtung fallen [..]

Wie kann ich diesen Satz anders sagen?

Comment: Es ist kein _"Satz"_, sondern nur ein Fragment, sorry.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Natürlich ist das ein Satz, auch wenn er mit einem Kleinbuchstaben anfängt.

Comment: @Robert: das sieht nicht aus wie ein kompletter Satz.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Wieso nicht? Subject, Modalverb, Objekt, Verb --- was feht?

Comment: @Es fehlt nichts, aber die `[...]` deuten wohl darauf hin, dass das ein Teil eines größeren Satzes ist. Also war er wohl nicht komplett. Grammatikalisch komplett vielleicht, aber nicht in Wirklichkeit.

Comment: Wie aus den Antworten und den Kommentaren dazu ersichtlich wird, wäre etwas mehr Kontext sehr hilfreich.

Comment: @IQV: stimmt. DerKontext ist wichtig hier, denn viele kennen den Begriff Gewichtung wohl nicht. Gewichtung ist mit welchem Faktor etwas in einer Formel mitberechnet wird. Z.B.: "Für die Berechnung des Lösungswirkungsindex *-- frei erfunden --*  wird der Alkoholgehalt mit 0.3 gewichtet. Wenn der Wert (des Alkoholgehalts) allerdings sehr hoch ist, kann die Gewichtung stärker sein, z.B. 0.7."

Answer (score 6):

Diese (vielleicht versehentliche) Variation von »ins Gewicht fallen« kenne ich auch nicht. Eine ähnliche Bedeutung haben

> - [stärker] zum Tragen kommen
> - einen [größeren] Effekt haben
> - sich [stärker] auswirken

woraus sich folgende Umformulierungen ergeben:

> - große Werte könnten stärker zum Tragen kommen
> - große Werte könnten [auch] einen größeren Effekt haben
> - große Werte könnten sich stärker auswirken

Comment: "Gewichtung" wird oft bei Bewertungen von Größen in einer Formel benutzt. Ich vermute mal, dass das hier auch der Fall ist. "In die Gewichtung fallen" wurde hier zwar analog "ins Gewicht fallen" gebildet, ist aber nicht genau das Gleiche.

Answer (score 4):

Meiner Meinung nach ist der der Ausdruck

> in die Gewichtung fallen

schlichtweg falsch. Eine einfache Google-Suche ergibt genau einen Treffer: Eben die hier gestellte Frage.

Möglicherweise ging dem Autor beim Schreiben der Ausdruck

> ins Gewicht fallen

durch den Kopf und da es irgendwie ähnlich klingt, kam es zu diesem Fehler.

Besser wäre:

> Große Werte könnten stärker bei der Gewichtung berücksichtigt werden.

Answer (score 2):

Ich kenne das nur als

> '*ins Gewicht fallen*',

meist graduiert mit '*nicht so stark*' oder '*kaum*' oder wie hier mit '*stärker*' bzw. '*stark*'.

In einer stark negativen Bedeutung kann man die Wendung auch so benutzen:

> Große Werte spielen hier kaum eine Rolle / haben hier kaum Bedeutung.

oder auch

> Es geht hier kaum um große Werte.

Der angegebene Textschnipsel ist ohne Kontext nicht klar zu verstehen. Vor allem den Konjunktiv 'könnten' verwundert, möglicherweise ist der Satz rein hypothetisch. Als weitere Alternativformulierungen könnte ich mir vorstellen:

> große Werte hätten (dann) ein stärkeres Gewicht [als z.B. die Hoffnung, schnelles Geld zu machen]
>
> übergeordneten Werten / den Leitzielen würde (so) eine größere Bedeutung zugemessen [als den taktischen Erfordernissen, die sich aus dem Tagesgeschäft ergeben]

Wenn ich so einen Satz lese, bin ich sehr auf der Hut. Wenn irgendwer "große Werte" für sich reklamiert oder diese von anderen einfordert, dann ist das Ergebnis oft bloße Sprachkosmetik oder sogar blanker Zynismus:

> Wir fühlen uns seit Generationen unseren Mitarbeitern verpflichtet und werden nach Kräften daran mitarbeiten, die Arbeitsplätze zu erhalten.

Leider sind die Kräfte dann im Ergebnis meist nicht stark genug, um die Abwanderung der Arbeitsplätze nach Südosteuropa oder nach Asien zu verhindern, oder sie reichen nur dazu aus, vor Ort eine Rumpfmannschaft zu erhalten. Denn leider gibt es ja noch andere "große Werte", nämlich die Verantwortung gegenüber den Aktionären. Das hört sich jetzt sehr platt an, aber so einfach läuft das oft.

Comment: Ich lese den Satz anders, aber es fehlt natürlich Kontext. Ich denken, dass es darum geht, dass große Werte den Ausgang stark beeinflussen können.

Comment: @Carsten: _In die Gewichtung fallen_ sounds odd to me.

Comment: Dem Teil stimme ich auf jeden Fall zu.

Comment: @Ralf: *Gewichtung* ist sowas wie ein Fachbegriff. Die Konstruktion mit "fallen" ist wohl nicht richtig, aber es wird nicht das Gleiche wie "ins Gewicht fallen" gemeint. Ist wohl eher "Die Gewichtung fällt für größere Werte stärker aus". Das bedeutet dass sie stärker gewichtet werden (also einen größeren Einfluss auf das Ergebnis haben als ihre eigentliche Größe annehmen lässt).

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: Ja, stimmt, und jetzt fällt mir auf, dass ich den Satz bzw. das Wort 'Werte' wahrscheinlich ganz falsch verstanden hatte: Es können schlicht und einfach 'größere Zahlen', 'größere Beträge' gemeint sein, dann ist die Antwort von Pollitzer die einzig richtige und meine Interpretation ein ziemlicher Quatsch bzw. allenfalls eine mit allerlei Eventualitäten behaftete und recht gewagte zusätzliche Deutungsmöglichkeit. Hatte ich bis jetzt gar nicht mitgekriegt. Danke!